# can someone explain to me this code? why it has -1 at the end?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, heap-randomization

this code takes input to define a range, then shows 6 numbers when the button is clicked. i dont understand why there is a -1 at the var digits = digits - 1. can you explain it to me? i'm just new here, i hope everybody understands

```js
function randomize() {
  var min = Number(document.getElementById('inputmin').value);
  var max = Number(document.getElementById('inputmax').value);
  var digits = 6
  var inside = Number(max - min);

  if (min > max) {
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = "please make the maximum number higher than the minimum";
  } else if (min == "" && max == "") {
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = "lacking numbers";
  } else if (min == "") {
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = "lacking minimum number";
  } else {

    myArray = [];

    var text = "";
    do {
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (inside)) + min;
      var noRep = myArray.includes(random);
      if (noRep == false) {
        myArray.push(random);
        text += " | " + random + " | ";
        var digits = digits - 1;
      }
    }
    while (digits > 0);
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = text;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>NO.1</title>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>
    <p>Enter Minimum Number</p>
    <input type="number" id="inputmin">
  </h1>
  <h1>
    <p>Enter Maximum Number</p>
    <input type="number" id="inputmax">
  </h1>
  <h1>
    <button type="button" onclick='randomize()'>Randomize!</button>
  </h1>


  <br/>
  <h1 id="answer"></h1>
  <br/>

</body>

</html>
```

i tried putting -2 and and it only shows 4 digits, i dont understand why

Comment: It's counting down from 6 to 1 using `while (digits > 0)`.

Comment: the code is poor ... while it doesn't break `var digits = digits - 1;` should be `digits = digits - 1;`

Comment: It makes the loop execute 6 times. A more normal way to write it would be `for (let i = 0; i < digits; i++)`

Comment: Pretty much all of the comments above me has said what I wanted to say, but just try to comment your code more. It helps you understand what you are trying to do and it helps others reviewing your code as well.

Comment: "i tried putting -2 and and it only shows 4 digits" Well, how many digits did you expect that it would show if you made this change? Why? Next: [did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [work through the code a step at a time](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), in order to see exactly what happens and in what order?

Comment: Hint: see where the code says `do` and then `while (digits > 0);`? So you know that this part of the code is in a loop, right? What needs to happen in order for the loop to exit? Should there be code that **changes** the value of `digits`, therefore? Now, where the code says `var digits = digits - 1;`, does this change the value of `digits`? Do you see how this relates to the loop?

Answer (score 2):

I added a few comments to the code. I hope this helps:

```js
function randomize() {
    // Get the min and max values from the input fields
    var min = Number(document.getElementById("inputmin").value);
    var max = Number(document.getElementById("inputmax").value);

    // Make sure the min is less than the max
    if (min > max) {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "please make the maximum number higher than the minimum";

        return;
    }

    // Make sure min and max are not empty
    if (min == "" && max == "") {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "lacking numbers";

        return;
    } else if (min == "") {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "lacking minimum number";

        return;
    }

    // Get the number of digits to generate
    var digits = 6;

    // Create an array to store the generated numbers
    var myArray = [];

    // Generate the random numbers
    var text = "";

    // Loop until we have generated the required number of digits
    do {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        var noRep = myArray.includes(random);

        // Make sure the generated number is not a duplicate
        if (noRep == false) {
            // Add the number to the array
            myArray.push(random);
            // Add the number to the text to display
            text += " | " + random + " | ";
            // Decrement the number of digits to generate by 1 so we know when to stop
            var digits = digits - 1;
        }
    } while (digits > 0);

    // Display the generated numbers
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: thank you very muchhhh!!! i reallt apreciate it. it's more clear now